# mark all children as checked

Tags: javascript, jstree

I am trying to make the following tree view: I am struggling to have the entire branch be marked as checked once a category is checked.
I am unsure how can I make my Treeview select all the children fields and mark their checkboxes as "checked" if the parent is checked.
any guidance/helpful tutorial is appreciated.
my Treeview.js

```
    $.fn.extend({
    treed: function (o) {

      var openedClass = 'glyphicon-minus-sign';
      var closedClass = 'glyphicon-plus-sign';

      if (typeof o != 'undefined'){
        if (typeof o.openedClass != 'undefined'){
        openedClass = o.openedClass;
        }
        if (typeof o.closedClass != 'undefined'){
        closedClass = o.closedClass;
        }
      };

        /* initialize each of the top levels */
        var tree = $(this);
        tree.addClass("tree");
        tree.find('li').has("ul").each(function () {
            var branch = $(this);
            branch.prepend("");
            branch.addClass('branch');
            branch.on('click', function (e) {
                if (this == e.target) {
                    var icon = $(this).children('i:first');
                    icon.toggleClass(openedClass + " " + closedClass);
                    $(this).children().children().toggle();
                }
            })
            branch.children().children().toggle();

        });

        tree.find('.branch>label').each(function () {
            $(this).on('click', function (e) {
                $(this).closest('li').click();
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });

    }
});
/* Initialization of treeviews */
$('#tree1').treed();
```

and here is my category view:

```
{!! Form::open(['route'=>'submit.category']) !!}
                    <h3>Category List</h3>
                    <ul id="tree1">
                        @foreach($categories as $category)
                            <li>
                                                    {{$category->title}}
                                @if(count($category->childs))
                                    @include('manageChild',['childs' => $category->childs])
                                @endif
                            </li>
                        @endforeach
                    </ul>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <button class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                            </div>

                        {!! Form::close() !!}
```

and here is managechild.php:

```
<ul>
@foreach($childs as $child)
    <li>
                  <label><input type="checkbox" value="{{$child->id}}" name="option[]">{{ $child->title }}
</label>
    @if(count($child->childs))
            @include('manageChild',['childs' => $child->childs])
        @endif
    </li>
@endforeach
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check below link, its tree structure and multiple other example like your requirement.

https://www.jstree.com/plugins/

Comment: I have tried to implement it, it required some weird data JSON structure and I am trying to keep my implementation as simple as possible.

Comment: Can you share me your HTML output or show me your blade file?